# Change image and add id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm kind of new in JS. I'm trying to write some script to change my images and add some id. I have two images and they are modals. When you click on them they display more options and then they replace image. I want to add some id and later write some function to sum up prices based on images. I hope you all are not confused of my language :)

My js to change img:

```
 function changeImage(element) {
    document.getElementById('myDivision').src = element;
}  

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var closeModalBtn = $('#myModal').find('.close-division').first();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.swap-img').on('click', function () {
            changeImage($(this).data('image'));
            closeModalBtn.trigger('click');
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Add your html code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to create the function `changeImage`.

You can change the source using jquery as well by just typing `$(this).attr('src', $(this).data('image'));`

Also to add id to any elemnt, you simply type
`$('YOUR_ELEMENT').attr('id', YOUR_ID)`. With the `.attr()` method you can create whatever attribute you want on an element and to retrieve the data from the attribute you can use `$(YOUR_ELEMENT).attr('ATTRIBUTE_NAME')`. Example to get the src, you can use `$(this).attr('src')`.

Please not that if you are using id to reference you element, u want to use `$('#YOUR_ELEMENT')`, if your using a class, then you use `$('.YOUR_ELEMENT')`

Comment: Thank you for that. Actually my JS is working very well as changing img. now I'm thinking about making an array based on this images. I want to have sth like that:
In Modal1 Pick 1st img -> in Modal2 Pick 2nd img -> get price.
I know that i have to create array & I have sth like this to display cost of first img:

Comment: $('#myID').attr('src');
    
var mydivision = [];
src["/path/to/img"]=6;
src["/path/to/img"]=6;
src["/path/to/img"]=6;
src["/path/to/img"]=6;
src["/path/to/img"]=6;
src["/path/to/img"]=7;

function getmyPrice () {
    var myPrice=0;
    
    var thedivis = document.forms["divisform"];

    var selectdivis = theForm.elements["myID"];

    return getmyPrice;
}

function getTotal () {
    var bestPrice = getmyPrice + //sth;

    document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Total Price $"+bestPrice; 
}

Comment: It is honestly hard for me to understand what you are saying when you say " In Modal1 Pick 1st img -> in Modal2 Pick 2nd img -> get price" and also the code below is a bit confusing but I will try to see what you are doing here

Comment: What you are saying is that for each image you pick u want to store the amount of that image in an array and add the amount for all the selected images?

But as a side note, you only need to create an array if you plan to use those amounts in more than one location. Otherwise you can just loop through all selected images and grab their value and sum them one time